# Angular 2 always places <style> tags at root <head>

Tags: jquery, html, typescript, angular, head

Unless the component has `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` all the `<style>` tags in the template are placed inside the `<head>` section of the main DOM. Is there any trick to crack this?

My use case is:

1. I load an external HTML template dynamically and embed it, creating a component.
2. I don't want the styles linked or embedded to affect the rest of the app.
3. I cannot use Native encapsulation, I have to keep the main DOM. That's because I use some jQuery libraries that manipulates the DOM, and they don't work as expected with Shadow DOM. This jQuery libraries work from directives loaded in this custom component.
4. I tried to replace `<link href="url">` with `<style>@import "url"</style>`, but their are always moved to the root `<head>` and affect to the whole app.

Any idea? If there is no way to solve this, I should have try to fix point 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The styles are rewritten so that the selectors contain the unique `_ngcontent-xxx` attributes that are added to each element and to only match these elements.

There is nothing you can do about styles being added to `<head>`.

If these styles affect other elements it might be a bug or you might use it in a way that emulation doesn't cover.

Comment: If I use `ViewEncapsulation.None`, the style are still moved to `<head>`. And they affect other elements (no matther the encapsulation option) because the don't get the unique attributes added, since they are external CSS.

Comment: I see. Why do you use `None`? This shouldn't be necessary in most cases. You can write the styles in a way that they can't conflict by adding an attribute to your component yourself like `Emulated` does yourself like `:host(my-component) { ...}` so they are only applied to `<my-component>` tags.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that the styles are external, totally out of my control.

Comment: I guess the browser doesn't support adding styles to elements without native shadow DOM therefore Angular2 can't do anything about it as well.

Comment: Okey, in that case I will focus my efforts trying to make jQuery plugin work with shadow DOM. Thank you!